# Can't run on Dev C++

Tags: c, dev-c++

I need help with my code. My code is in C source format, but it can't run on the Dev C++ software. I had checked with my teammate several times, there is no error with my code, but it just can't run. Someone, please help me with it. Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define TAX 0.08

void getInput(struct order myOrder[], int order);
void processOrder(struct order myOrder[], int order);

struct order
{
    char productID[6];
    float unitPrice, grossTotal, netTotal, serviceTax;
    int qtyOrdered;
};

main() 
{
    struct order myOrder[50];
    int order;
    printf("ORDER PROCESSING\n");
    printf("=================\n");
    printf("How many orders today ? ");
    scanf("%d", &order);
    getInput(myOrder, order);
    processOrder(myOrder, order);
    system("PAUSE");
}

void getInput(struct order myOrder[], int order)
{
    for (int i = 0;i < order;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter productID :");
        scanf("%s", &myOrder[i].productID);
        printf("Enter unit price : RM ");
        scanf("%f", &myOrder[i].unitPrice);
        printf("Enter quantity ordered : ");
        scanf("%d", &myOrder[i].qtyOrdered);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void processOrder(struct order myOrder[], int order)
{
    float sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0;i < order;i++)
    {
        printf("Order : %s\n", myOrder[i].productID);
        printf("Unit Price : RM %.2f\n", myOrder[i].unitPrice);
        printf("Qty Ordered : %d\n", myOrder[i].qtyOrdered);
        myOrder[i].grossTotal = myOrder[i].unitPrice * myOrder[i].qtyOrdered;
        printf("Gross Revenue : RM %.2f\n", myOrder[i].grossTotal);
        myOrder[i].serviceTax = myOrder[i].grossTotal * TAX;
        printf("Service Tax : RM %.2f\n", myOrder[i].serviceTax);
        myOrder[i].netTotal = myOrder[i].grossTotal - myOrder[i].serviceTax;
        printf(": : Net Revenue : RM%.2f\n\n", myOrder[i].netTotal);
        sum += myOrder[i].netTotal;
    }
    printf("* TOTAL INCOME EARN :: RM%.2f", sum);
}
```

Comment: What does "just can't run" mean?

Comment: C programs are compiled and executed from top to bottom. In the way you write the code. So you can't make references to things that you haven't written yet or plan to write further down.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `struct order` should be before usage of that.

Wrong:

```
void getInput(struct order myOrder[], int order);
void processOrder(struct order myOrder[], int order);

struct order
{
    char productID[6];
    float unitPrice, grossTotal, netTotal, serviceTax;
    int qtyOrdered;
};
```

Correct:

```
struct order
{
    char productID[6];
    float unitPrice, grossTotal, netTotal, serviceTax;
    int qtyOrdered;
};

void getInput(struct order myOrder[], int order);
void processOrder(struct order myOrder[], int order);
```

Also `scanf("%s", &myOrder[i].productID);` is wrong. `char*` (pointer to a character) should be passed for `%s`, not `char(*)[6]` (pointer to entire array). The `&` should be removed.